# Opening ArcGIS Desktop layer package (.lpk) file using QGIS on Mac?

Tags: qgis, convert, zip-codes, layer-file, layer-package

I downloaded an LPK file from the Esri site that contains USPS defined zip codes. I'm working with QGIS on a Mac, so I converted the file to a .zip. There's a .lyr file that opened up in the zip, but I'm not able to open that up on QGIS.

Is there a way to convert the contents of an Esri layer package file (.lpk) into a shapefile with the associated data, and that I can open with QGIS on a Mac?

I looked into using utilities like 7-zip, but it doesn't seem to work on a Mac.

Apparently one of the .xml files in the layer package should contain a link to the actual data under the packagelocation tag, but I wasn't able to find that tag in the .xml files.

Does anyone know if that tag name might have switched?

Answer (score 9):

From the Comments it appears that the asker solved this by unzipping the *.lpk to find a *.sdc file that was then converted to shapefile format using instructions from [NCSU Libraries' Geospatial Data Formats](http://www.lib.ncsu.edu/gis/formats.html) page:

> With ESRI Data and Maps 2006, a standalone "Data Distribution
>   Application" was included that converts SDC data files directly to
>   shapefiles. This application may be downloaded from the [Geodata
>   Server](https://www.lib.ncsu.edu/gis/geodata) at http://gisdata.lib.ncsu.edu/esri2006/data_maps/DDA/
>   [needs credentials] or off-campus from here [needs authentication]. A
>   help file is also included at this download location.

Answer (score 6):

You just need 7zip. The archives that Esri uses are basically zip files but winzip and windows default zipping does not work. Use 7zip to unzip a layer package LPK,OR Mobile map package or VTPK or TPKX

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for zip code boundaries in other formats, you should turn to the US Census Bureau:

Go to: http://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2013/main and choose "zip code tabulation area"

Comment: ZCTAs are not zip codes, which are used the USPS. ZCTAs are a Census Bureau invention roughly based on zipcodes but tailored to their needs. I've seen some estimates put the correlation to be only ~80%

Answer (score 2):

Right click and extract the .lpk file using unzipping software. With a certain lpk file I then searched around and found a folder in the extraction that contained shapefiles.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer I work here.**

---

You can get US Zipcode Boundaries via this API:

https://www.boundaries-io.com

The  API shows US Boundaries(GeoJson) by zipcode,city, and state.
you should use the API programatically to handle large results.

[image]

Comment: This website seems to have gone offline sometime since the answer was posted.

Comment: @larsks https://www.boundaries-io.com is the company page ,thanks.i will update the answer..MashApe was brought out by RapidAPI which hosts.  Thanks.