# Exporting layer from ArcMap with detail

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers

How can I Export layer from ArcMap with complete detail contain picture of symbol?
[image]

Export by click right on layer and export data was tested. I actually just want to Export layer with symbols.

Answer (score 2):

*Save as Layer File* just below the Export option in your snip is designed for this purpose. It does not contain data though. If you need data and all layer properties, you can try Create Layer Package option.

Comment: thanks.this way export layer for importig layer(with complete detail like symbol and founts) in Arcmap,But I want to use this export for using in QGIS(https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64309/opening-arcgis-desktop-layer-package-lpk-file-using-qgis-on-mac) in attach link others advise to convert *.lpk file to *.zip but when you convert , layer lose other detail like symbols and ....// Do you know other way ?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24300/adding-layerfiles-lyr-to-qgis and/or https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64309/opening-arcgis-desktop-layer-package-lpk-file-using-qgis-on-mac